# Difference between parallel adder and serial adder when adding two binary numbers

Tags: digital-logic

I am having a hard time understanding difference between parallel adder and serial adder when adding two binary numbers. Wikipedia does not have any information, and google image search is bringing me almost nothing. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add two N-bit numbers, a parallel adder will use N copies of a full-adder circuit, and it will produce a result in one clock cycle.

On the other hand, a serial adder will use just one full-adder circuit, but it will require N clocks to produce the result.

The tradeoff is circuit complexity (and power consumption) vs. time.

Some examples: A desktop PC uses a parallel adder, because it wants to be able to do as much arithmetic as possible in a given amount of time, and there is no real restriction on how much power it can consume. On the other hand, a handheld calculator only needs to be as fast as the human operating it, but it needs to last a long time on a small battery, so it uses a serial adder.

Comment: "a parallel adder ... will produce a result in one clock cycle." except for small but irritating problem of the (ripple) carry (or it must be a very long clock cycle).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: No, carry look-ahead logic makes it (near-)constant time.

Comment: Yep, but it that case your N-bit adder will be (much) more than just N 1-bit-full-adders!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I can't tell ... are you making a point that's actually relevant to the original question?

Comment: Your first line states/implies that an N-bit parallel adder is JUST N-copies of a full-adder and PRODUCES A RESULT IN ONE CLOCK CYCLE. In contrast with a serial adder, who needs N clocks. That comparison is misleading because a serial adder needs no carry-look-ahead logic, but a parallel adder does (for a compareable clock speed), and this is is significant part of a parallel adder.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I think Wouter's point is that adding carry logic necessarily lengthens the critical path, so comparing the (long) clock cycle of the parallel adder to the 32 (short) clock cycles of the serial adder isn't an apples-to-apples comparison.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I never said "just"; that's something that you unfortuately read into it. The gist of my answer is about the space/time tradeoff.

Comment: @trentcl: A single full adder requires a minimum of 3 gate delays to produce a 2-bit result. A carry-lookahead adder requires only 4 gate delays to produce a result with any number of bits (ignoring any penalty for high fan-in gates). The difference in clock periods is negligible.

Comment: But IMO for the space-time tradeoff you should mention the carry-lookahead, which is a significant part of the space of a parallel adder, especially if it wants to be N times as fast as a serial adder. @trentcl: WITHOUT the lookahead (hence ripple-carry) a parallel adder has little advantage over a serial adder. With the lookahead it is significantly larger than N full-adders.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I really don't think the OP was looking for that level of detail; the question is very generic. But since we're here, consider this: When you take into account the various registers required, a *pipelined* parallel ripple-carry adder is *exactly* N times the logic of the serial adder, and runs at exactly the same clock speed.

Comment: Agreed, but it can't deliver the result in one clock cycle, so the useability is quite low. Try it for the PC incrementer...

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Sure, that's a pathological case. There are plenty of counterexamples. For instance, heavily pipelined arithmetic sometimes makes a lot of sense in FPGA-based DSP.